# Unable to store dynamic arrays in binary files

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I require the ability to store arrays within a structure and then save the structure as a byte file. The problem is that I require the array to be dynamic. Pointer arrays are out of the question as when it comes to saving it only saves the pointer and vectors won't work. Here is an example of the current setup I am using.

```
struct GenerationBase
{
    //float value[];                // Will override data currently in ram
    //float value[10];              // Dose not work as it needs to have a dynamic size
    //float* value;                 // Will only save the pointer value
    //std::vector<float> value;     // Dose not work for some reason
};

template<typename T>
void write_to_file(std::ofstream& stream, T data)
{
    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(T));
}

int main()
{
    const char* file = "file.txt";

    GenerationBase write{};

    std::ofstream stream_write(file, std::ios::binary);

    write_to_file(stream_write, write);

    stream_write.close();

}
```

Comment: Consider using `De/Serialiazation`.http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: sizeof(T) is a compile time thing - it is not an option if your array is dynamic

Comment: A `vector` is more complicated than a simple array of data. You cannot just take the address of it.

Comment: The `sizeof(T)` should have been an indication that this won't work.  If you had 1 item in that vector, or 1,000 items, you would have seen that `sizeof(T)` remains the same value.

Answer (score 0):

All the notes in the comments are correct - you have to use some library for serialization. protobuf, boost::serialization are good binary formats, JSON and XML are good choices for text storage.

There is more fundamental problem with this approach, however the byte composition of your struct depends on many things: compiler, endianness, 32 or 64-bit architecture. That means that you cannot simply store the byte contents of a C++ data structure in a file.

Answer (score 0):

When using structs with dynamic size in the sense of "size will be determined at runtime rather than at compile time", then you can use an array of unspecified size like `float value[]` as the last member of that struct. Note, however, that you will have to "manually" allocate memory of proper size for the struct. This has been the case for C, and it is also the case for C++. Unfortunately, it's rather tricky to manually define the size when using operator `new`, since `new` uses the type to determine the size, not any runtime value. So you'd probably use `malloc` and `free`, which looks somehow misplaced in C++.

An easier solution would be to use a `std::vector` and not write a dump of the structs memory but rather the content of the vector.

Anyway, for each approach you follow, you will have to write also the number of elements in the array to the file; otherwise - at least if you write several such structs sequentially into the same file - you might loose the information how many elements the (dynamic) array stored in the file actually has. An then, of course, the read-in process has to take this number into account and create/modify the `structs` accordingly.

See the following code which demonstrates both (1) the vector approach and (2) the struct with variable size approach. Hope it helps somehow.

```
struct GenerationBase_UsingVector
{
    std::vector<float> value;

    void write(std::ofstream &w) const {
        size_t num_elems = value.size();
        w.write((const char*)&num_elems, sizeof(num_elems));
        w.write((const char*)value.data(), num_elems*sizeof(float));
    }

    void read(std::ifstream &r) {
        size_t num_elems;
        r.read((char *)&num_elems, sizeof(num_elems));
        float f;
        while (num_elems--) {
            r.read((char *)&f, sizeof(f));
            value.push_back(f);
        }
    }
};

struct GenerationBase_PlainArray
{
    size_t num_elems;
    float value[];

    static GenerationBase_PlainArray* create(size_t num_elems)
    {
        GenerationBase_PlainArray* result = (GenerationBase_PlainArray*)malloc(sizeof(GenerationBase_PlainArray) + num_elems*sizeof(float));
        result->num_elems = num_elems;
        return result;
    }

    static struct GenerationBase_PlainArray* newFromStream(std::ifstream &r) {
        size_t num_elems;
        r.read((char *)&num_elems, sizeof(num_elems));
        GenerationBase_PlainArray* result = GenerationBase_PlainArray::create(num_elems);
        r.read((char *)result->value, num_elems*sizeof(float));
        return result;
    }

    void write(std::ofstream &w) const {
        w.write((const char*)&num_elems, sizeof(num_elems));
        w.write((const char*)value, num_elems*sizeof(float));
    }
};

int main() {


    GenerationBase_UsingVector gb_vector_forwrite;
    gb_vector_forwrite.value.push_back(1.0);
    gb_vector_forwrite.value.push_back(2.0);
    gb_vector_forwrite.value.push_back(3.0);
    gb_vector_forwrite.value.push_back(4.0);
    gb_vector_forwrite.value.push_back(5.0);
    gb_vector_forwrite.value.push_back(6.0);

    std::ofstream write("test.bin", std::ios::binary);
    gb_vector_forwrite.write(write);
    write.close();

    GenerationBase_UsingVector gb_vector_forread;
    std::ifstream read("test.bin", std::ios::binary);
    gb_vector_forread.read(read);
    read.close();

    for (auto f : gb_vector_forread.value) {
        cout << f << endl;
    }

    GenerationBase_PlainArray* gb_array_forwrite = GenerationBase_PlainArray::create(6);
    gb_array_forwrite->value[0] = 1.0;
    gb_array_forwrite->value[1] = 2.0;
    gb_array_forwrite->value[2] = 3.0;
    gb_array_forwrite->value[3] = 4.0;
    gb_array_forwrite->value[4] = 5.0;
    gb_array_forwrite->value[5] = 6.0;

    std::ofstream write2("test2.bin", std::ios::binary);
    gb_array_forwrite->write(write2);
    write2.close();
    free(gb_array_forwrite);

    std::ifstream read2("test2.bin", std::ios::binary);
    GenerationBase_PlainArray *gb_array_forread = GenerationBase_PlainArray::newFromStream(read2);
    read2.close();

    for (int i=0; i<gb_array_forread->num_elems; i++) {
        cout << gb_array_forread->value[i] << endl;
    }
    free(gb_array_forread);

}
```